# Struts 2 sessionToken interceptor always redirects to error

Tags: struts2, double-submit-prevention

I have been attempting to get the tokenSession interceptor to work (Struts 2.0.14) but always get the warnings:

```
2013-03-13 08:32:09,395 [17] DEBUG Intercepting invocation to check for valid transaction token. | org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.doIntercept(128)
2013-03-13 08:32:09,395 [17] WARN  Could not find token name in params. | org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper.getTokenName(124)
2013-03-13 08:32:09,396 [17] DEBUG no token name found -> Invalid token  | org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper.validToken(154)
2013-03-13 08:32:09,397 [17] WARN  Could not find token name in params. | org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper.getTokenName(124)
2013-03-13 08:32:09,397 [17] WARN  Could not find token mapped to token name null | org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper.getToken(105)
2013-03-13 08:32:09,398 [17] DEBUG Forwarding to location /WEB-INF/view/support/TokenError.jsp | org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(113)
```

The struts.xml has the following interceptor configuration:

```
            <package name="survey" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="csv"
                     class="webapp.CsvResultType"/>
            </result-types>

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="log"
                class="struts.LoggingInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor name="formAuthentication"
                class="security.FormAuthenticationInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="default">
                <interceptor-ref name="log"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="formAuthentication"/>
                <!--interceptor-ref name="chain"/>-->
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
            <interceptor-stack name="defaultTokenStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="default"/>
            </interceptor-stack>

        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="default"/>

        <!--  -->

        <global-results>
             <result name="blank">/WEB-INF/view/support/Blank.jsp</result>
             <result name="error">/WEB-INF/view/support/Error.jsp</result>
             <result name="insufficientPrivileges">/WEB-INF/view/support/InsufficientPrivileges.jsp</result>
             <!--result name="file" type="file"></result-->
        </global-results>

    </package>
```

With the action definitions:

```
<package name="respondent" namespace="/respondent" extends="survey">
    <action name="*" class="controller.respondent.{1}Action">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultTokenStack"/>
        <result name="list">/WEB-INF/view/respondent/{1}List.jsp</result>
        <result name="edit">/WEB-INF/view/respondent/{1}Edit.jsp</result>
        <result name="view">/WEB-INF/view/respondent/{1}View.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/respondent/{1}.jsp</result>
        <result name="invalid.token">/WEB-INF/view/support/TokenError.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

The jsp has the token tag:

```
<s:form action="FunctionSummary.action" method="post">
<s:token/>

    <table class="buttons">
        <tr>
            <s:if test="surveyStarted">
                <td><s:submit value="Resume Survey"/></td>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <td><s:submit value="Start Survey"/></td>
            </s:else>

        </tr>
    </table>

</s:form>
```

Any access to this page always results in redirection to the invalid.token result and the warnings above.

I have validated that without the interceptor configured, the page source does have the token but I cannot get the sessionToken interceptor to see it.

Any help would be most appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: You are using a really old Struts2 version.  Upgrade to version 2.3.8 and try again.

Comment: What do you mean by "any access to this page"? Are you using this action to show this page? Token interceptor should be configured on action that you submit to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your `<s:token/>` tag into your `<table>` tags.
I got the same problem just like you. And after I put `<s:token/>` into `<table>` tag problem solved.

```
<s:form action="" id = "" theme="simple" method = "post">
<table id = "" border="1" width="200">
    <s:token/>  <!-- In the table tag -->

</table>
</s:form>
```

Comment: The `<s:token>` tag have to be inside form tag. It doesn't matter if it is in table tag or not.